# How can the level curves of a quadratic form be a pair of lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, curves

$x_1^2+4x_1x_2+4x_2^2=1\Rightarrow A\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow f_A(A)=\begin{vmatrix}1-\lambda&2\\2&4-\lambda\end{vmatrix}\Rightarrow\begin{Bmatrix}\lambda_1=0\\\lambda_2=5\end{Bmatrix}\\
\Rightarrow q\,(\vec{x})=5c_2^2
$

---

Why is this a pair of lines, and not a parabola - how does $5c_2^2=1$ yield anything other than a quadratic function?

---

EDIT:

After some tinkering, I'm convinced that the level curves look like this:[image]

What's unclear is how I would graph these w.r.t both $x_1,x_2$ as well as the principal axes $c_1, c_2$ as we do with ellipses and hyperbolae. Where would these two lines be on this graph? Neither of them are functions of $c_1, c_2$. Is there some obvious change of coordinates that I'm not seeing here?[image]

Comment: why are we speaking in terms of $x$ and $y$, and not $\left\{x_1,x_2\right\}$ or $\left\{c_1,c_2\right\}$? My issue is the change of basis, I think.

Answer (score 3):

$$x_1^2 + 4x_1x_2+4x_2^2 = (x_1+2x_2)^2$$
Therefore the function is constant on lines of constant $x_1+2x_2$, which are straight lines.

(Note also that the determinant of the quadratic form's matrix is equal to zero, so you have at least one eigenvector with eigenvalue zero, which is bascally the same thing.)

Comment: Should these "level curves" be graphed w.r.t the $x_1-x_2$ plane, or the $c_1-c_2$ plane? I'm used to graphing ellipses or hyperbolae w.r.t. the principal axes of the quadratic form (i.e. the eigenspaces of $A$). Does $c_1=0$ imply that the origin is a point of reference? Very confusing.

Comment: They are related by linear transformation, so I don't think it makes that much difference. And, if I understand your notation, you do not have $c_1=0$: $c_1$ does not affect the value of your function, which, setting $c_2=(x_1+2x_2)/\sqrt{5}, c_1 = (2x_1-x_2)/\sqrt{5}$ (purely for orthogonality), gives the quadratic form $ 0c_1^2 + 5c_2^2 $.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a quadratic form as a "norm" on the vector space. The level curves of the quadratic form are the "spheres" of the norm.

In this case, since $\lambda_1=0$, the "norm" of every vector is $5$ times its component in the $\lambda_2$ direction.

To your question about $5c_2^2=1$, I should hope that this does not give a parabola! This equation involves only one variable, not two.